# innerHTML overflowing parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-material

I'm using the Material Design components in my Angular 4 app, the MdCard in particular. I am dynamically creating cards based on results I retrieve from an http request response. The responses are strings, but could have HTML tags such as `<b></b>` in them, hence I'm using [innerHTML] to do this as follows:

```
        <md-card-title-group>
          <md-card-title [innerHTML]="result.title"></md-card-title>
          <md-card-subtitle [innerHTML]="result.link"></md-card-subtitle>
        </md-card-title-group>
```

However, I'm finding that with longer strings (in mobile view), the title and subtitle overflows the md-card border. I have tried using the `overflow` css property, but this doesn't seem to work.

Any help is great.

Comment: If other css rules add `whithe-space:nowrap` your text will never wrap to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show a live example of it? It is hard to know what is happening without looking at an example.

There is some ways of dealing with text-overflow is CSS. You can try:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

or cut the text with

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Neither of those two work, but I did manage to figure out how to do it just by fiddling with some css properties. Turns out that I had to use non-standard css for WebKit to achieve it. `word-break: break-word;` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment on @Glauber Ramos answer, I managed to fix the issue using non-standard webkit css.

`word-break: break-word;`